# Consequence of Yitang Zhang's prime k-tuple paper

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Yitang Zhang initially published the paper stating;

$P_{n+1}-P_{n} \leq k$, where $k$ was equal to $70,000,000$ occurs infinitely often.

I am well aware that this number has since been shaved down alot. However, my question is; as a consequence of this, has he proved that there are infitely many primes that occur  with a gap of $k>70,000,000$, or whatever the current value for $k$ stands at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as, one can easily generate infinitely many arbitrarily long sequences of composite numbers: For fixed $k$ and arbitrary $a > 0$, all of the $k$ numbers
$$a (k + 1)! + 2, \ldots, a (k + 1)! + (k + 1)$$ are composite (as they are respectively larger than but divisible by $2, \ldots, k + 1$), so the gap between the largest prime $< a (k + 1)! + 2$ and the smallest prime $> a (k + 1)! + (k + 1)$ is *at least* $k$.

To my knowledge no $k$ is known, however, for which there are infinitely many prime gaps of size *exactly* $k$, though Zhang's bound and its improvements guarantee that some such $k$ exists. Of course, the truth of this for $k = 2$ is the content of the Twin Prime Conjecture. (I'm not sure whether it has been improved since then, by the way, but last year the [Polymath Project reduced Zhang's lower bound to $246$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897).)